# How do I pause an HTML video and resume automatically over a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a 4 second long video embedded in my HTML page using video tag. I need to pause the video for 2 secs first at 2.99s, 3.44s and then at 4.00s. For that to happen the video needs to resume from previous instance.

But after long hours of effort I haven't been able to find a solution. Thus far I have just been able to get the video paused for >=2.99s but it does not resume even after I had used setInterval function.

Here is the code:

```
var vTag = document.getElementById('video');

setInterval(function() { pVideo();}, 2000);

function pVideo() {
      vTag.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
      cTime = vTag.currentTime;
      (cTime >= 2.9 || cTime >= 3.44 || cTime >= 4.00) ? vTag.pause(): vTag.play();
 };
};
```

PS: The video is being used as a background video for header section.

Comment: What does the console log `cTime` as? (Not sure why this question was downvoted.. it's clear and concise..) Also, just as a node, you can do `setInterval(pVideo, 2000);` to reduce code clutter. No params means you can just pass a function reference.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks for the response. I wonder the same! cTime as expected prints out the time values in seconds.

Comment: I think I see why. In your if statement, all your conditions will always be true after 2.9 seconds.

Comment: Yes but why does not setInterval function work? I mean should it not start over after 2s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.. this is a fully working code

**HTML**

```
<video id="video" autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**JS**

```
var vTag = document.getElementById('video');
vTag.play();
var wasPausedBefore1 = 0;
var wasPausedBefore2 = 0;
var wasPausedBefore3 = 0;

vTag.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
    cTime = vTag.currentTime;
    if (cTime < 1) { 
        wasPausedBefore1 = 0; 
        wasPausedBefore2 = 0; 
        wasPausedBefore3 = 0;
    } else if (cTime > 2.8 && cTime < 3.1 && wasPausedBefore1 == 0) {
        vTag.pause();
        wasPausedBefore1 = 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            vTag.play();
        }, 4000);
    } else if(cTime > 3.3 && cTime < 3.6 && wasPausedBefore2 == 0){
        vTag.pause();
        wasPausedBefore2 = 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            vTag.play();
        }, 4000);
    } else if(cTime > 3.8 && cTime < 4.0 && wasPausedBefore3 == 0){
        vTag.pause();
        wasPausedBefore3 = 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            vTag.play();
        }, 4000);
    }
};
```

And here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o9mknsx0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

I'm not sure if you'd be able to catch the times you need using `timeupdate` since it fires either every 200ms or 250ms but I'd do it like so:

```
var vTag = document.getElementById('video');

vTag.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    var cTime = vTag.currentTime;
    if(cTime === 2.99 || cTime === 3.44 || cTime === 4)) {
        vTag.pause();
        setTimeout(function() {
            vTag.play();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

For it to catch your times like `2.99` and `3.44` then you need to poll for it every `10ms` using `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var cTime = vTag.currentTime;
    if(cTime === 2.99 || cTime === 3.44 || cTime === 4) {
        vTag.pause();
        setTimeout(function() {
            vTag.play();
        }, 2000);
    }
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this code (tried it again to be doubly sure!). The problem with this approach is that this does not even pause the video!
Moreover, we cannot expect `===` to work since I read the timeupdate event triggers every 250ms

Comment: @unclesam I've added another method using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Tried that! Didn't work! One things for sure you will never be able to catch the exact time, you might have to use a range. Tried that too, didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your if statement to track the pause values somehow, otherwise your video will not play because after 2.9 seconds, the if will always return true for all those conditions.

```
var vTag = document.getElementById('video');

setInterval(pVideo, 2000); //function reference

var nextPause = [2.9, 3.44, 4.00];
var pauseIndex = 0;
function pVideo() {
    vTag.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
        cTime = vTag.currentTime;
        var pauseTime = nextPause[pauseIndex];
        if (cTime >= pauseTime) {
            vTag.pause();
            setTimeout(vTag.play, 2000); //unpause after 2 seconds
            if (++index <= nextPause.length) index++
            else index = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

This is untested and my logic may be flawed, but I feel like the concept is sound.

Put all your pause times into an array, and track the last used index (resetting as well, if need be (looping video)). Then, if the if statement matches, pause the video and run a timeout for 2 seconds to play the video again.

Comment: Just tried that out! The same result as original! Pauses after 2.9s but never resumes. I believe either the code never executes the setTimeout function or I am trying to implement something impossible! BTW is there a way if we operate on frames by any means?

Comment: That part I'm not sure. Try doing some logging in the timeout I put into the if statement, see if it's even executing

Comment: I tried out this:
`setInterval(pVideo, 2000); //function reference

var nextPause = [2.9, 3.44, 4.00];
var pauseIndex = 0;
var index = 0;
function pVideo() {
    vTag.ontimeupdate = function(e) {
        cTime = vTag.currentTime;
        var pauseTime = nextPause[pauseIndex];
        if (cTime >= pauseTime) {
            vTag.pause();
            console.log(cTime);
            setTimeout(vTag.play, 2000); //unpause after 2 seconds
            console.log(cTime);
            if (++index <= nextPause.length) index++
            else index = 0;
        }
    }
};`